# I need libphp7.so module to configure apache on Centos

Tags: php, apache, centos, php-7

I follow the tutorial of this [link](https://wiki.php.net/phpng#how_to_download_build_install_and_test) to use php7 or phpng on my Centos 6.5 with apache.

I can execute php scripts in the console but I would like to be able to run php scripts using the Apache Server.

I need some help because I can't find the libphp7.so module. I don't know if I have to build it or what.

Comment: Serve PHP over FPM and then you don't need to build the `libphp7.so` module.

Comment: @N.B How to Serve PHP over fpm? I run the `php-fpm`.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 here's the walkthrough: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/serve-php-php-fpm-and-nginx/

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to add `--with-apxs2` to your configure script. According to the link you provided I do not see that in the configure flags. `--with-apxs2` will "Build shared Apache 2.0 Handler module". You may also need to make sure in your apache configuration you have:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The first time I built php7 it just displayed the source rather than execute it, but adding that caused it to execute the code.

If you want to try it out with Docker I just created a Docker image for PHP7 at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/silintl/php7/ You can also just view the Dockerfile which includes all the commands used to install and configure it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. After configuring and compiling with `--with-apxs2` flag the following files have been created automatically: 
`/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so`,
`/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.load`,
`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.load`.

Comment: Thank @Phillip very much!

Answer (score 3):

In my config file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf` which is loaded by the parent config file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I found the following default configuration:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !prefork.c>
    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Using information provided by @JanePage and @PhilipShipley, i change it to this:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and Apache started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Phillip who gaves some clues for this issue, but in my case I've solved my problem this way :

1 - Copy the Library php7.so that you have into apache module directory  with this command : 
sudo cp  /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so  /opt/bitnami/apache2/modules

2 - Add in your Apache config file following code :

LoadModule php7_module ./modules/libphp7.so

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

And PHP worked fine after that !