# Install PHP 7.2 on Centos 7

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos7, httpd.conf

I following this [link](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-centos-7/) to upgrade my php from 5.6 to 7.2
and its successfully installed

```
PHP 7.2.14 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2019 12:06:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.14, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

here my httpd

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov  5 2018 01:47:09
```

after trying to phpinfo() I got apache doesn't works. **Its produce php code rather than compiling.**

I check my httpd.conf, there are no LoadModule for php7Module. So I add LoadModule as bellow

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and checking libphp7.so and guess what, there are no `libphp7.so` at modules directory.

However, I still figuring out what I miss. I install bellow dependencies

> php72 php72-php-fpm php72-php-mysqlnd php72-php-opcache php72-php-xml
>   php72-php-xmlrpc php72-php-gd php72-php-mbstring php72-php-json

Ps. I running `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

**Update 1**

```
getsebool -a | egrep 'cgi|builtin_scriptin'
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
```

I think that *PHP isn't enabled in Apache.* How to make it works?

Comment: Everything i could find on the problem points out only two things: 1) modules/libphp7.so seems to just not be created/is missing when installing php from centos repos(i found at least 5 articles that describe the same problem CentOS, which stated that). 2) The easiest way to solve this is get libphp7.so somewhere else. Or compile php yourself. Unfortunatelly i coudn't verify either of these two statements.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin agree with you. I still finding workaround solution for that

Comment: can you please provide the output of the following command? `yum list installed | grep php`

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart/start apache2

> sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

If still issue persists, then

> sudo systemctl status httpd.service

Comment: as I mentioned before, there are no libphp7.so, so your solution wouldn't work. it will produce error `httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: ...directory`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126134/i-need-libphp7-so-module-to-configure-apache-on-centos

Comment: Have try, check my `httpd.conf`

Comment: tried 'a2enmod php7.2' or 'a2enmod php7.2.4'  and then restarting httpd service ?

Comment: a2enmod is a debianism, on CentOS you will need to do this manually. Please refer to the Apache documentation to find out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html